# Getting rid of padding or marging from bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment, grid-layout

I'm using bootstrap (version 3.3.6) for the first time to make my site. Readed the docs and start to code. Excluding the `<link>`'s the code below is my site's structure:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-1">
            <div class="loader">
                <div class="loader-bg">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-lg-push-1">
            <div class="black-box">
                <p class="info-message">Coming <span>VERY</span> soon!</p>
                <p class="text-message">Until then, my contacts:</p>
               ...
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Using **push** and **pull** classes I thought I was removed padding for the columns. Setting the main div with 'class="container"' I have the result:

[image: layout with class=container]

Changing to 'class="container-fluid"' the behavior remains strange. Notice shapes overlapping page:
[image: layout with class=container-fluid]

What I want in my results is: the circle and rectangle (both are divs) remains aligned to the edges of the page (left and right) with no padding or marging. Following docs until now doesn't work. What this behavior occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default `col-*` have `padding` so you just need to reset them

```css
[class^="col"] {
  padding: 0
}
[class$="-2"] {
  background: orange
}
[class$="-10"] {
  background: grey
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader-bg">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
      <div class="black-box">
        <p class="info-message">Coming <span>VERY</span> soon!</p>
        <p class="text-message">Until then, my contacts:</p>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```